# How to add radioButton elements to spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I have a spinner to which I have to add list with radio buttons. How should I do it?

Comment: Please clarify your question: what is your html/css code for the spinner, what is the javascript framework that are you using (or is it a simple html?). And where do you want to add your buttons?

Comment: @Dmitry Negoda: A spinner has notthing to do with HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a custom layout for the items of the spinner in drop down mode and also implement a custom adapter which uses this layout and handles the radio buttons. Check [this tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/12/custom-arrayadapter-for-spinner-with.html) to see how the customization of an adapter works.